# Backup folder to group of devices

Tags: debian, backup, rsync, duplicate

I have a mounted SD Card of 64Go, I would like to backup every pictures on it to multiple USB keys which are 32Go each with a simple script. 
Is it possible to fill the first USB key and then continue on the second USB key with a rsync ? I have tried multiple things, but every time I result with the same data on the two keys. I am currently using Debian 7.

Comment: After you backup your pictures once, do you plan to (1) leave the two USB keys intact, delete the originals eventually, take new pictures and copy them to *another pair* of USB keys? and another, and another. Or to (2) update your backup periodically using the same pair of USB keys? (while pictures on the SD card may be deleted, added, renamed etc. and backup should reflect this). In other words: do you want to (1) distribute files into two directories only? Or to (2) distribute *and* keep in sync without unnecessary copying (`rsync`-style)?

Comment: It should be a backup station, so yeah it could be different USB keys, the rsync style.

Comment: So… both? Many sets of USB keys in sync with the same SD card?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: Do you need every USB key to be readable on its own? If so, then there may be situations (while updating the backup) when files that were copied earlier need to be moved between two USB devices to make room for some new large file. This reduces your options. There are tools to distribute a directory content into multiple directories of given size, but then resyncing may be very problematic (if not started from scratch). You can have easy resyncing if you allow e.g. RAID0, but then you cannot read just a single device; and mounting will not be straightforward. Which features do you really need?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `rsync`, you can use the program [n2ncopy](https://sourceforge.net/projects/n2ncopy/?source=directory) to copy, or move, multiple files and folders to multiple destinations in only one step.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm trying to perform that on Debian 7, and it seems that this software it is only working on Windows.

Comment: Oh ok, I'll edit your question to add this information for users who try to solve your question in the future.

Comment: Rip someone downvoted me for editing your question and providing an answer for windows